# Meaning of ―speemodustriculation―

Tags: meaning

> The country had rushed into a carnival of wild industrial
>   speemodustriculation, of rising prices, of "labor scarity" and the
>   highest wages ever paid.

The word/sentence comes from a private collection book.

Comment: It looks like a word the author has coined themselves, as a portmanteau of several other words. Probably only someone familiar with the field would be able to tell what those words are supposed to be.

Comment: Some possibilities may be "speculation", "emotional", "gestriculation", "industry".

Comment: Please cite the work and author - inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Speemodustriculation** is almost certainly a "[nonce word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word)":

> A nonce word (also called an occasionalism) is a lexeme created for a
>   single occasion to solve an immediate problem of communication.

The meaning is presumably a mixup of "speed", "modernism", "industrialization", and something that I don't immediately recognize for the "culation" piece, but only the author (if even he) would know with any certainty.

Comment: Matriculation came to mind.